# Ставится ли запятая перед "даже хмурясь"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия, частица

*Я тобой не налюбуюсь...

Ты прекрасна, даже хмурясь.*

Answer (score 1):

Запятую надо поставить: **Ты прекрАсна, даже хмурясь.**

Деепричастие и отнесенная к нему частица обособляются, так как в данном предложении является аналогом придаточного предложения: Ты прекрасна, даже когда хмуришься.

А вот **пример, где одиночное деепричастие не обособляется**, выполняя функцию наречия:

Вечером принесу вам лекарство, ― сказала она **хмурясь** (=хмуро). [Юрий Трифонов. Предварительные итоги (1970)]

Answer (score 1):

Тут частица *даже* употреблена для смыслового выделения деепричастия *хмурясь* и сама по себе не требует постановки запятой, но деепричастие *хмурясь* должно быть обособлено.

Общее правило таково — одиночные деепричастия обособляются (выделяются с обеих сторон запятыми), если выражают дополнительное действие, и не обособляются, если выражают оттенок основного действия. В данном случае одиночное деепричастие *хмурясь* выражает дополнительное действие и должно быть обособлено (вместе с усиливающей его частицей *даже*).

Comment: Да, деепричастие выражает дополнительное действие, но почему Вы так считаете?

Comment: @Jasmin, Она хмурится и при этом остается прекрасной. Два разных действия. "Хмурость" — не оттенок "прекрасности" и не обстоятельство, относящееся к  "прекрасности".

Comment: Может быть, деепричастие в принципе не может являться  обстоятельством образа действия по отношению к краткому прилагательному?

Comment: @Jasmin, Интересная мысль. Нигде ее не встречал, но думаю, Вы правы.

Comment: @Jasmin, Деепричастие, относящееся к именному сказуемому, выраженному кратким прилагательным, — редкий случай.

Comment: Пожалуй, не только редкий, но и невозможный.

Comment: @Jasmin, Почему невозможный? Об этом пишут.  "Реже примыкает к именному сказуемому" (https://sci.house/kultura-rechi-stilistika-scibook/prichastie-deeprichastie-pravila-obrazovaniya-84426.html)

Comment: Спавший опершись на локоть? Это они сами придумали, для доказательства классика нужна.

Answer (score 0):

*Ты прекрасна даже хмурая.*

ДАЖЕ, частица. Употребляется для смыслового выделения слов. Не требует постановки знаков препинания. Равна по значению частице И, ср.: *И хмурая ты прекрасна.*

Предложение, предложенное Вами для анализа,  составлено неверно: деепричастие должно обозначать добавочное действие и не может относиться к составному именному сказуемому, где основную смысловую нагрузку несёт краткое прилагательное и сведена к минимуму функция нулевой связки. Деепричастие в редких случаях может относиться к причастию или деепричастию, которые, как известно, образованы от глагола, - но не к прилагательному.

Comment: "Реже деепричастие примыкает к именному сказуемому, выраженному кратким страдательным причастием, кратким прилагательным или существительным." ( https://sci.house/kultura-rechi-stilistika-scibook/prichastie-deeprichastie-pravila-obrazovaniya-84426.html). То же здесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Спасибо, ссылки посмотрела. Честно говоря, статьи неубедительны, нет ни одного примера, иллюстрирущего примыкание деепричастия к существительному или краткому прилагательному. Поищу более серьёзные источники доказательств Вашей правоты. Если найду, удалю свой ответ и, конечно,  благодаря Вам обрету новое знание. Спасибо!

Comment: Валгина, Розенталь Фомина http://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-308.shtml Реже деепричастие примыкает к именному сказуемому, выраженному кратким страдательным причастием, кратким прилагательным и существительным: В полдень, переходя на станции через рельсы, он был оглушен неожиданным свистком паровоза (Купр.); Проведя этот вечер с невестой у Долли, Левин был особенно весел (Л. Т.); Пушкин, не утрачивая в настоящем и будущем своего значения как поэт великий, тем не менее был и поэтом своего времени, своей эпохи (Бел.).

Comment: Нашел авторитетный источник, но в примерах не просто именное сказуемое, а **составное именное** (везде есть глагольная связка), и это заставило меня самого сомневаться по поводу нашего случая.

Comment: Я сама придумала примеры, но во всех деепричастия переходят в наречие-определение при отглагольном существительном: ответ походя,смеясь; признание плача; чтение лёжа, сидя,стоя.